# Pass info between methods

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I want to use data which I got in my onCreate() in another method. I know that this is basic Java but I can't get this specific thing to work. 
The scenario: A user shares an image via his gallery to my app. I receive the uri via intent and want to make a toast showing the uri. So far so good. This is what I got:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
    // Handle incoming shared image
    // Get intent, action and MIME type
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleWrongContent(intent); // Handle text being sent
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleWrongContent(intent); // Handle multiple images being sent
        }
    }
 ...
}

private void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    String str = intent.getParcelableExtra("imageUri").toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

If I try this out now, I get this NPE:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String     
java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `intent.getParcelableExtra` is returning null. There is no key called `imageUri` in intent probably. You can check using `hasExtras()` before getting it to prevent NPE.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but how can I check the right extra key I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intent.getParcelableExtra` is returning null. There is no key called `imageUri` in intent probably. You can check using `hasExtras()` before getting it to prevent NPE.

Also instead of `imageUri`, try to use `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`. Check [Handle the Incoming Content](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content) at [Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html). Quoting it, try to use:

```
void handleSendImage(Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        // Update UI to reflect image being shared
    }
}
```